# cakephp 2 - Could not send email. on windows using gmail

Tags: email, cakephp-2.0

I have this config:

```
class EmailConfig {

  public $default = array(
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 465,
        'username' => 'myemail@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'mypassword');
}
```

And code this:

```
 $Email = new CakeEmail('default');
 $Email->viewVars(array('first_name' => $user['User']['first_name'], 'link' => $link, 'last_name' => $user['User']['last_name'], 'otp' => $otp, 'html_link' => $html_link));

 $Email->to($username);
 $Email->emailFormat('both');
 $Email->from('myemail@gmail.com');
 $Email->subject("Course Registration");
 $Email->template('welcome');
 $Email->send();
```

This works great on my mac, no problems but on my coworkers windows box, he gets this error:
Could not send email

Can someone explain why?

```
Request URL: /Users/activate/165
Stack Trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\cakephp\lib\Cake\Network\Email\MailTransport.php(47): MailTransport->_mail('pradhan.sabin@g...', 'Course Registra...', '--20cbbe22cace5...', 'From: mmassites...', NULL)
#1 C:\wamp\www\cakephp\lib\Cake\Network\Email\CakeEmail.php(1066): MailTransport->send(Object(CakeEmail))
#2 C:\wamp\www\cakephp\app\Controller\UsersController.php(727): CakeEmail->send()
#3 C:\wamp\www\cakephp\app\Controller\UsersController.php(665): UsersController->otpactivation('165')
#4 [internal function]: UsersController->activate('165')
#5 C:\wamp\www\cakephp\lib\Cake\Controller\Controller.php(486): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(UsersController), Array)
#6 C:\wamp\www\cakephp\lib\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php(187): Controller->invokeAction(Object(CakeRequest))
#7 C:\wamp\www\cakephp\lib\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php(162): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(UsersController), Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#8 C:\wamp\www\cakephp\app\webroot\index.php(109): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#9 {main}
2013-06-07 21:09:31 Error: current url is :/Users/activate/165
```

Comment: take a look at this to make sure it has ssl connectivity:  http://serverfault.com/questions/59873/what-are-the-possible-causes-of-this-error-unable-to-connect-to-ssl-smtp-g

Comment: I noticed on my mac that even though I have my email client configured to go to google, it seems to be using my local mail server, why is this? Is there a way to get it to go directly to google and bypass local mail server?

Answer (score 0):

ok, so the bottom line is it looks like unix/php needs a mail server locally to work,  unlike ruby/rails which can talk to a remote server directly. Windows does seem to have a way to make this work.

On windows there is a way to do it by editing your php.ini:

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=465
```

I haven't tested this so I am not sure if it works. This was for a college who uses windows.